# Flatten a tuple and keep the corresponding values for every value of the tuple

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe ('mass_grouped3'):

```
value1 value2
aaa    (123, 1234)
bbb    (321, 4321)
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
value1 value2
aaa    123
aaa    1234
bbb    321
bbb    4321
```

I want to create new dataframe, I am using this code:

```
new_df = ({'value2' : [item for sublist in mass_grouped3['samples_from_tuple'] for item in sublist], 'value1' : mass_grouped3['value1']}
```

But the part of the code for the second value of the new df
 is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: split `value2` into two columns and `melt`

Comment: look at explode: `df.explode('value2')`

Comment: @anky_91 thanks for this I just didn't know how to formulate my question and couldn't find anything. I fixed my code.

Comment: @Y.C.T you mean my code above in the comment doesnt work?